Visualizing or Interacting with the Higgs Field
I'm not a physicist, but I'm curious about how one could "see" or "interact" with the Higgs field in a visual way. For instance, placing ferrite dust on a table with some magnets allows us to "see" the magnetic field interact with the dust. Is there a way to achieve something similar with the Higgs field or any other fundamental fields that are said to permeate all of space (besides gravity)? If so, could you provide an example or a link to a video demonstrating this?
I apologize for my lack of formal knowledge in this area, but any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Leptons having masses seems pretty visual in a bubble chamber to me.

Well, if you have a scale and step on it, it will tell you your weight.
Let's say your weight is 100kg (please let me know if you need modification), then around 1kg is coming from the quark's mass gaining from the Higgs field. And if you are lately on diet, you can feel and see that your interaction with Higgs field is decreasing.
Therefore, the effect of Higgs field is in full display and can be visualized.

So does it not have field lines? Is it a physical field?

Does the field exist literally, or is it just a mathematical field that models reality?

@Wesley Jones: Does the magnetic field exist literally, or is it just a mathematical field that models reality?

When did physics get so complicated.
